# Filter a picklist value in aggregate query

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a use case where I need to show the count of only certain picklist values. So I have used aggregate query with only picklist values but how to set them each individual picklist values (type__c) in wrapper class to get each count of those values

Lightning Component:

```
 <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
                <div style="margin-bottom:-2rem" class="slds-grid slds-gutters">
                    <div class="slds-col">
                        <div style="margin-top: 10px;" >Open</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col open-churn">
                        <div class = "closed-text">{!v.lstwrap[0].count}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col">
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col open-churn">
                       <div class = "closed-text">{!v.lstwrap[0].count}</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col">
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col open-churn">
                        <div class = "closed-text">'Value C'</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col">
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col open-churn">
                        <div class = "closed-text">'Value D'</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I dont want to be in Aura:Iterator. I need to set the values for 'A','B','C'&'D'. If i dont find values i need to set it as '0'.

```
 List<aggregateResult> resultsOpen = [Select count(id) totalCount,Type__c type from Business_Support_Case__c where Account__c IN: AccId 
                                         AND CreatedDate >= LAST_N_MONTHS:3 AND Case_Status__c IN ('New') 
                                         AND Type__c IN ('a', 'b','c','d') GROUP BY Type__c ];
    for (AggregateResult ar : resultsOpen)  {
                cCountWrapper objWrap = new cCountWrapper (Integer.valueOf(ar.get('totalCount')), (String)ar.get('type'));
                lstWrap.add(objWrap);
            }
            return lstWrap;
```

Wrapped Class:

```
public class cCountWrapper{
    @AuraEnabled
    Integer count{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    String type{get;set;}

    cCountWrapper(Integer count,String type){
        this.count = count;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. It looks like you should already be getting the values you need to display. What output are you getting? Any errors?

Comment: @sfdcfox ...Yes Am getting the values. I have a lightning component where the structure is pre-defined. For example 'Count of Picklist value 'A' need to placed in that box'. For that, I would need 4 different wrapper to set the values of 'A','B','C'& D

Comment: It sounds like you need a Map instead of a Wrapper. Or something else. What is the format your component expects?

Comment: @sfdcfox...as of now I am making it as List and sending to controller. If I put {!v.lstWrap[0].count} am getting the values. But it shouldn't be in that way due to structure of lightning component. I need something like For 'Box A' it needs to have 'Box A' value, for 'Box B' it needs to have only B value. Thanks for your Help!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to demonstrate what you'd like your component's markup to look like. Also, you can do the change in either Apex or JavaScript, which would you prefer?

Comment: Answered it as I had code ready. :P

Comment: @sfdcfox ...I have added my lightning component as well.Please let me know if this works. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a wrapper, use a simple map. The following changes should suffice:

```
@AuraEnabled public static Map<String, Integer> getTypes(Id AccId) {
  // Note: values here will be cAsE-sEnSiTiVe. Pay attention...
  Map<String, Integer> results = new Map<String, Integer> {
    'A' => 0, 'B' => 0, 'C' => 0, 'D' => 0
  };
  for(AggregateResult ar: [
      Select count(id) totalCount,Type__c type from Business_Support_Case__c where Account__c IN: AccId 
              AND CreatedDate >= LAST_N_MONTHS:3 AND Case_Status__c IN ('New') 
              AND Type__c IN ('a', 'b','c','d') GROUP BY Type__c]) {
    results.put((String)ar.get('type'), (Integer)ar.get('totalCount'));
  }
  return results;
}
```

Now, in your component:

```
<div class="slds-col">
    <div style="margin-top: 10px;" >A</div>
</div>
<div class="slds-col open-churn">
    <div class="closed-text">{!v.lstwrap.A}</div>
</div>
<div class="slds-col">
    <div style="margin-top: 10px;" >B</div>
</div>
<div class="slds-col open-churn">
    <div class="closed-text">{!v.lstwrap.B}</div>
</div>
<div class="slds-col">
    <div style="margin-top: 10px;" >C</div>
</div>
<div class="slds-col open-churn">
    <div class="closed-text">{!v.lstwrap.C}</div>
</div>
<div class="slds-col">
    <div style="margin-top: 10px;" >D</div>
</div>
<div class="slds-col open-churn">
    <div class="closed-text">{!v.lstwrap.D}</div>
</div>
```

The most challenging part will be paying attention to case sensitivity of the variables. However, by using a Map, you'll get the layout you're looking for.

---

Alternative solution:

Given the original wrapper class, you could also:

```
action.setCallback(this, result => {
  component.set("v.lstwrap", result.getReturnValue().reduce((a,v) => a[v.type] = v.count), {});
});
```

Where we use Array.prototype.reduce to convert the return value into an Object where the keys are the "type" from the wrapper, and the values for those keys are the numbers. You would also still want to make sure that each type was returned:

```
Set<String> remainingTypes = new Set<String> { 'A','B','C','D' };
for (AggregateResult ar : resultsOpen)  {
    cCountWrapper objWrap = new cCountWrapper (Integer.valueOf(ar.get('totalCount')), (String)ar.get('type'));
    remainingTypes.remove(objWrap.type);
    lstWrap.add(objWrap);
}
for (String remainingType: remainingTypes)  {
    cCountWrapper objWrap = new cCountWrapper (0, remainingType);
    lstWrap.add(objWrap);
}
return lstWrap;
```

Either way, once mapped to an Object, you can refer to each count result by name, as demonstrated earlier in this answer.